# jQuery Spinner Control Appears Below Text Box

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery spinner tool found here:

http://btburnett.com/spinner/example/example.html

When I try using it, the spinner control appears below the text box. Can anyone explain this one? I have an example of what's going on here:

http://jsfiddle.net/brandonnicoll/bMUtt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link the `ui.spinner.css` file too.

Check the Resources in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bMUtt/17/

Here is the content of `ui.spinner.css`:

```
.ui-spinner {position: relative}
.ui-spinner-buttons {position: absolute}
.ui-spinner-button {overflow: hidden}
```

Comment: @Nikanoru - Please consider accepting Alex's answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: I plan to, but it says I still need to wait three more minutes